# How to stop python-social-auth and reverse a transaction during pipeline step?

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I have a Django application which uses python-social-auth for authentication.

I have this in my django settings:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    ...
    'my.app.my.custom.pipeline',
)
```

How do I stop the whole user creation process in my custom pipeline?

I have tried throwing various exceptions including `ValueError` and `AuthException` but the created users remain in the database. Doesn't throwing an exception reverse the database transaction?

Comment: your custom pipeline comes before or after the create_user function? If the user has been already created you'll need to remove it manually, throwing an exception will cause the pipeline to stop, but already saved data still remains.

Comment: @abidibo My custom pipeline comes at the very end. Deleting the user manually could work, but the pipeline creates some other data in the database as well. I am looking for a cleaner solution that is implementation independent, for example reversing the whole transaction would the trick, but how do I do that?

Comment: maybe you can wrap the login view in a transaction (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/transactions/), but I've never done it before

Answer (score 1):

Define a view in one of your Django app and don't forget to register a path for it:

```
def access_denied(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>Access denied</h1>")
```

And then, the function registered in your custom pipeline just needs to return the view :

```
if not allowed_email(fields["email"]):
    return redirect(access_denied)
```